# Homebrew in OS X 10.9.2: Error: SHA256 mismatch

Tags: shell, homebrew

```
brew install php55
==> Downloading http://www.php.net/get/php-5.5.11.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror
######################################################################## 100.0%
Error: SHA256 mismatch
Expected: 60e14c255f2a461a7a26639b84a2fc448cc2f91c8dead0e9fd00cd8ba27a2e96
Actual: 0d9438c2557db5809f4232148ca1567516e7ece9bf8726853ceac4a111cb8690
Archive: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/php55-5.5.11
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
```

I tried

> brew cleanup && brew update

but not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some one face the same issue.
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/875

"I checked the downloaded file, and it's the html download page rather than the tarball.

It looks like php now wants the URLs to be in the form of http://www.php.net/get/php-5.4.22.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror instead of http://www.php.net/get/php-5.4.22.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror

EDIT: I'm totally mistaken with this. from/this/mirror is the correct one, but it's borked on php's side."

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem with MongoDb. I was able to fix it first I changed the permission to admin.

Then I ran

```
brew cleanup && brew update
```

After that I ran

```
brew install mongodb
```

and it worked like a charm

Comment: I had to  uninstall, `brew cleanup`, and then reinstall.

Answer (score 19):

I also tried brew cleanup and brew update but still got the same issue so i did this

```
brew edit <application>
```

and replaced sha256 value with actual value shown in error msg.

and this worked out for me, hope it helps you too.

Comment: This one's the best!

Comment: I did this, but what are you supposed to do after the sha256 message is replaced by the correct one?

Comment: @XelaVi Run install again.

Comment: As quirky as this workaround suggestion is, it works for whatever reason lol. I think it should be marked as the accepted answer.

Comment: So, if the reason for the failing signature is that a malevolent actor has replaced the file with a trojanized version, you think it's acceptable solution to ignore that fact?

Comment: Anecdote: I'm trying to move forward whatever homebrew casks still build on a machine stuck on Mojave (macos 10.14), and finding that this option *does not* resolve the pervasive SHA256 hash conflicts. In particular, I'm getting a SHA256 conflict for `berkeley-db`, but `brew edit berkeley-db` does not contain *any* hashes matching the offended "expected" SHA256. I'm not sure the exact cause, or whether/how this could be traced back to Mojave no longer being supported.

Answer (score 4):

```
Error: libvirt: SHA256 mismatch
Expected: ac06a7b7a74cf83e953f50e33455df97fc87880ebdac4f1dca89a62331375b1a
  Actual: 3346ebf9df9fc4dd37b4c0a5bf1ce80a577b97a7a48dac3febf22aa857be9a98
    File: /Users/mek/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/6287efc2ec4d5147e8389b97caeb20dd0d4acec390b5910b2454a4dd018654c1--libiscsi--1.19.0.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
```

To resolve above error run below commands:

- rm "filename"
- brew install "package" -f

Comment: Anecdote: I'm trying to move forward whatever homebrew casks still build on a machine stuck on Mojave (macos 10.14), and finding that this option *does not* resolve the pervasive SHA256 hash conflicts. These may or may not reflect applications that no longer compile on Mojave? Error message is not completely clear.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with watchman.

```
brew install watchman
```

response for :

> ==> Installing dependencies for watchman: automake, pcre
>
> ==> Installing watchman dependency: automake
>
> ==> Downloading https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/automake/automake-1.16.1.tar.xz Already
>   downloaded:
>
> /Users/piccolo/Library/Caches/Homebrew/automake-1.16.1.tar.xz
>
> ==> Downloading https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/automake.git/patch/?id=a348d83
>   Already downloaded:
>
> /Users/piccolo/Library/Caches/Homebrew/automake--patch-7a57ca2b91f7f3c0b168cf5ffbc8a1b2168f3886bcadcc15412281472dace3ce.git
>
> Error: SHA256 mismatch Expected:
>
> 7a57ca2b91f7f3c0b168cf5ffbc8a1b2168f3886bcadcc15412281472dace3ce
>
> Actual:
>
> c048ce853eef073a5dfce34fcf9af786e8525e384e01dbbf4e6066623985d4c7
>
> Archive:
>
> /Users/piccolo/Library/Caches/Homebrew/automake--patch-7a57ca2b91f7f3c0b168cf5ffbc8a1b2168f3886bcadcc15412281472dace3ce.git
>
> To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.

then I did this:

```
brew uninstall automake
brew cleanup
brew update
brew install watchman
```

Then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I got fix, using steps wrote by MoOx:

```
cd /Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/
```

and delete manually the package and run again`brew upgrade` works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you may have a package that have a new SHA (eg: github updated the way it compress tar.gz), so best thing to do is to fix the original formula (you can try locally and also push your change upstream).

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if a corporate security policy intercepts the request to the cask and responds with an Access Blocked page instead. You can tell by seeing the file's URL rewritten and its content being HTML. In that case you have to ask them to relax the policy or you're out of luck.

Answer (score -1):

Also ran into this just recently, turned out my proxy settings had been removed somehow, so double checking could be helpful.