# SHA-256 checksum error while installing gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, sha256, gnuplot-iostream

I unfortunately keep getting this error, while trying to install gnuplot (with x11) - even after deleting the announced file an try it again...

[image: install error]

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work for you, but first do this:

```
brew cleanup && brew update
```

and then try again. More info in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23273713/homebrew-in-os-x-10-9-2-error-sha256-mismatch). Hope it helps!